# My java game isn't working

Tags: java

So i'm still a beginner but I managed to get this code but it didn't work like I wanted, my main problem is that every time I press 1 it resets the enemy instead of keeping the same one. I would really appreciate if someone could help me. So far I have only made writing 1 do something.

```
package Game;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random r = new Random();
        System.out.println("Welcome to Dragon Heart");
        System.out.println("1. Start");
        System.out.println("2. Quit");

        int input = 0, enemyhealth = 75, enemyattack = 15, playerhealth = 100, playerattack, random;
        boolean enemydead = true, playerdead = false;
        input = in.nextInt();

        if (input == 1) {
            System.out.println("Game started!");
            while (0 != 1) {
                if (enemydead = true) {
                    enemyhealth = r.nextInt(50) + 51;
                    enemyattack = r.nextInt(15) + 6;
                    System.out.println("An enemy appears, it has " + enemyhealth + " health points and " + enemyattack + " attack points");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("The enemy now has " + enemyhealth + "health points");
                }
                System.out.println("1. Attack");
                System.out.println("2. Defend");
                System.out.println("3. Run away");
                System.out.println("4. Do nothing");
                input = in.nextInt();
                if (input == 1) {
                    playerattack = r.nextInt(5) + 21;
                    random = r.nextInt(2) + 1;
                    enemyhealth = enemyhealth - playerattack;
                    if (random == 1) {
                        playerhealth = playerhealth - enemyattack;
                    }
                    if (enemyhealth <= 0) {
                        enemydead = true;
                        System.out.println("The enemy has been killed");
                    } else {
                        enemydead = false;
                    }
                }

            }

        } else if (input == 2) {
            System.out.println("Game quit.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please change your title to reflect the actual problem. We know your game isn't working. You wouldn't have posted otherwise.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm just not sure how I could explain the problem. If you could give me a suggestion I would change the name.

Comment: Set a title that will reflect in general the problem you're experiencing. Write inside the post, when you encounter the problem and what the problem is. If it's exception than also include the `stacktrace`. And any more information you can add, just add. We're here to help you, but you need to guide us first.

Comment: @Tiny `0 != 1` looks quite `true` to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your logic for defense away is dubious, but your problem is here:

```
if(enemydead = true)
```

You're reassigning `enemydead` to `true` every single time.

You really want to check if the enemy is dead, which is accomplished with this:

```
if(enemydead)
```

Further, you could clean up `while (0 != 1)` to be `while(true)` instead.  However, you're going to need to include a `break` statement somewhere in that loop so that it's not an infinite loop like it is now.

Lastly, it's a good idea to have [lower-case package names](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) as opposed to upper-case package names.

Comment: Ah yes, that's it... I knew there was a problem with that line.

To clarify the answer here, when doing comparisons, you use ==.  = is an assignment operator, which means enemydead is being set to true every time that if statement is called, so your enemy is always dead.  Use a == operator to compare or, as he mentioned, since enemydead is a Boolean value, you can simply use if(enemydead).

Comment: Just to clarify, `if (enemydead == true)` would still be a correct condition, since `==` vs `=` is often a mistake we all make in the beginning :)

Comment: @vikingsteve:  While you're technically correct, I've got several warnings set up in my IDE and some 5 years of conditioning that prohibits me from ever writing a boolean comparison and then comparing it against `true` or `false`.

Comment: You are of course correct, and most IDE's should allow you to simplify the condition, having said that - a basic understanding of what is going on is important to beginner java programmers :)